# how to select particular cells in excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

im trying to select cell B4 and all the cells from column A to Z and row 10 and below, so basically A10:Z150. And trying to unlocked it before i protect the sheet. 
Right now im using Sheets("DR02").Range("B4", "A10:Z200").Locked = False but its not working. Its only unlocking cells above row 4 instead of only cell B4.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
  With Sheets("DR02")
    .Unprotect "password"
    .Range("B4,A10:Z200").Locked = False 
    .protect "password"
  End With
```

Or (to get the last row in column "A"):

```
With Sheets("DR02")
 .Unprotect "password" 
 .Range("B4,A10:Z" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Locked = False
 .protect "password"
End With
```

**EDIT**:

From comments it seems that cell `B4` is merged with other cells if so then we can use:

```
With Sheets("DR02")
 .Unprotect "password"
  Union(.Range("B4").MergeArea, .Range("A10:Z" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)).Locked = False
 .Protect "password"
End With
```

Comment: its giving me follosing error Unable to Set the Locked Property of the Range Class

Comment: @T.Patel, see the edit , and change `password` to your password

Comment: Yes, i have unprotected the sheet first. for some reason "B4,A10:Z200" is giving me "Unable to Set the Locked Property of the Range Class". And "B4","A10:Z200" is not giving me any error but its only unlocking rows above 4.

Comment: and when i remove cell B4, everything is working fine. Means that its everything is locked above row 10 and thats what it should be. So not sure what is causing the problem when i add cell B4 in to the equation.

Comment: so you have cell `B4` merged?

Comment: Fadi, thanks for your responses. Your edited code is almost right, i just had to take out period in front of each Range function. So this Union function did the magic. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Union(Range("B4").MergeArea, Range("A10:Z" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)).Locked = False